# can I set a regexp for an object's method/property selector?

Tags: javascript, regex, object, methods, properties

```
var regxp = /[\S]/; //any char, not sure if it's /.*/ or something else
var obj = {
 atr1: "bla"
}
var blahs = obj[regxp]; //returns atr1
```

I'm looking for a shortcut to get methods/properties names from an object, because `for..in` is slow compared to a for loop for instance.
I want this for a special case when I know the object will have only one method/property

Comment: `var obj = {
 atr1 = "bla"
}` What's that?!

Comment: var obj = { atr1 : "bla" } is the correct way, but i dont really undertand the question

Comment: so what is the purpose of the regex

Comment: @tenshou, M totally stranger to Javascript but if you know name of an property, you have object also and if that attribute is public then cant you directly access property just by using object.property syntax? Most of the OO languages use the same technique to access properties/ methods.

Comment: If you know the object will only have one property why even use an object?

Comment: Ok fixed it, sorry I was like super tired when I done this. The reason for this is to GET the name of the property, WHATEVER it is. to make a function to get that name. only that.

Comment: @nnnnnn : this is it, I don't know the name of the property, that's why I was curious if it's possible to match it with a regexp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Yes*, you can try to access a property of an object using a regular expression but *no*, it won't do what you want: it will convert the regex into a string and use that property name.

The only way to find a property name on an object by matching a regular expression is a `for ... in` loop, like you mentioned.  The performance should not be an issue if the object has only one property.

```
function findPropertyNameByRegex(o, r) {
  for (var key in o) {
    if (key.match(r)) {
      return key;
    }
  }
  return undefined;
};
findPropertyNameByRegex(obj, regxp); // => 'atr1'
```

Comment: Yes, I was afraid that this is the case..thank you, and sorry for everyone to come up with a dummy question like this!

Answer (score 1):

your regex will match a single non-space character.

`for...in` *is* a loop. it's slower than what exactly? have you benchmarked?

if you want to look up properties using a regex, you'll have to do it in a loop.

```
for(var k in obj) {
    if(regexp.match(k)) {
      // do whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: "compared to a for loop for instance". I was curious if there is a way to match the property name of an object with a regexp, so I don't have to use a `for in` loop.

Comment: and yes, I've benchmarked, it's like ten times slower than a normal `for (i;i<length;i++){}` loop [link](http://jsperf.com/array-and-object-loops)

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one property, you can be pretty sure `for..in` will not be slow.