# How do you build a case insensitive REST API using Express and Node JS

Tags: node.js, rest, express, coffeescript

I use an express controller method like below. How do I make sure, I'm able to read properties either from {"Name" : "Sam", "EmpId": 1} or {"name" : "Sam", "empId": 1}

```
app.post '/api/employee', (req, res) ->
    employee = new EmployeeModel({
      Name: req.body.Name,
      EmpId: req.body.EmpId
    })
    employee.save (err) ->
      if (err)
        res.send err
      else
        res.send employee
```

Comment: Hunch: create a copy of the object with only lowercase property keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know it's only two configurations why not try:

```
app.post '/api/employee', (req, res) ->
    employee = new EmployeeModel({
      Name: req.body.Name || req.body.name,
      EmpId: req.body.EmpId || req.body.empId
    })
    employee.save (err) ->
      if (err)
        res.send err
      else
        res.send employee
```

Otherwise you would need a `for...in` loop as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223258/can-i-set-a-regexp-for-an-objects-method-property-selector).

Comment: I needed it from all my controller route methods (so ended up writing the for loop and have all route methods go through this -  @lowerCaseRequestBody = (body) ->
    newbody = {}
    for key, value of body
      newbody[key.toLowerCase()] = value
    return newbody